# Free particle in momentum representation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, density-operator, partition-function, volume

In Greiner, density operator for a free particle has been calculated in momentum basis.
They consider a large box of vilume $V=L^3$ and periodic boundary condition.
$$\phi_\vec{k}(\vec r)=\frac{1}{\sqrt V}\exp\left(i\vec k\cdot\vec r\right)$$
$$\vec{k}=\frac{2\pi}{L}(n_x,n_y,n_z);\,n_i=0,\pm 1,\pm2,...$$

Canonical partition function,
$$Z(T,V,1)=\sum_\vec{k}\exp\left(-\frac{\beta\hbar^2}{2m}\vec k^2\right)\tag{1}$$
$$\implies Z(T,V,1)=\frac{V}{(2\pi)^3}\int d^3\vec k \exp\left(-\frac{\beta\hbar^2}{2m}\vec k^2\right)\tag{2}$$
While going from discrete sum to integral i.e., from $(1)$ to $(2)$, how the factor $\frac{V}{(2\pi)^3}$ appears?
Mathematically, I am not able to see how this factor comes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1 dimension, with periodic BC of length $L$,  the  momemtum eigenvalues are
$$
k_n = \frac{2\pi n}{L}
$$
then  $f(k_n)$ will be a slowly-varying function of   $n$ when $L$ is large. Then we have  $dn= (L/2\pi)dk$ and
$$
\sum_n f(k_n) \simeq  \int f(k_n)dn =\frac{L}{2\pi}\int f(k)dk. 
$$
Same in higher dimensions.

Comment: Thabks a lot for the reply  In the last expression, you have taken $\sum_nf(k_n)$. I am taking $\sum_{k_n}f(k_n)$. Why are we not considering the latter one?

Comment: Is that not the same thing?

Comment: I think no. Because in the latter, the integral itself is in the variable $k$. But in former we get integral in variable $n$ and after transforming to $k$ we get the factor of $\frac{V}{(2\pi)^3}$

Comment: You are summing over the set of $k_n$. You can label the entries in the set  by $k_n$ or just by $n$. It's the same set of numbers $\{k_n\}$  in each case.